# How to select depending on the col value

Tags: mysql, split

I have a table and how the table is populated is someone sends a text to my number and then that text will be automatically inserted to the table. We have a format to follow for the person that's going to send the text.

Then I use substring_index to parse out the text and uses the delimiter period (.)
Its easy if the text that was sent is in format but if its not the table I have looks sloppy. What i'd like to happen is if the text that was sent doesn't have the period it won't do the substring index and if it have a period it will do the substring

---

I think I'm going to use the `LOCATE` command

Just wondering how I can do this the correct way

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE column = LOCATE('.',`column`)
```

It have an output but its not complete, what I'd like to happen is something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `it will only show where the value of locate is 0`
```

nvm got it, i did it like

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE LOCATE('.',`column`) = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking my recent posts and I want to share that for this post what I did was use SUBSTRING_INDEX.

For example for the string KL, 222, JL, 15

I wanted to get the string 222

I first tried

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('KL, 222, JL, 15', ',', 2)
```

the output was

```
KL, 222
```

then what i did another substring_index and copied the one I already did and did it like this

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('KL, 222, JL, 15', ', ', 2), ', ', -1)
```

then got the result that i want which is `222`

:)

Answer (score 0):

Then you want a case statement.  Somewhere along the way, you have code like:

```
substring_index( . . . )
```

Wrap this in a `case`:

```
(case when text like '%.%' then substring_index( . . . ) end)
```

Comment: oh yea i'll try that as well